# Why is C++ range adaptor closure pipeline operator not working

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am creating a version of `std::ranges::to` as a learning experience. My version is named `convert` since that is what `to` does. The code within the `#if` will not compile, but I don't understand why.

One guess is the pipeline operator is not working despite having the `struct` inherit from `range_adaptor_closure` because of something I'm missing.

The other is the `convert<vector>` expression is atypical since other views aren't templates.

I'm not looking to produce production-level code, only learn the mechanisms.

It is available on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fe8hTKTvE)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

namespace rng = std::ranges;
namespace vws = std::views;
namespace detail {
//------------------------------------------------
template <typename ConT>
struct Convert : rng::range_adaptor_closure<Convert<ConT>> {
    template <rng::range Rng>

    constexpr auto operator()(Rng& src) -> ConT {
        return ConT{rng::begin(src), rng::end(src)};
    }
};

template <typename ConT>  //
inline detail::Convert<ConT> convert;
}  // namespace detail
//--------------------------------------------------
// handles container with no <type>: to<vector>
template <template <typename> typename Con, rng::range Rng,
          typename T = rng::range_value_t<Rng>>
auto convert(Rng&& src) -> Con<T> {
    return detail::convert<Con<T>>(src);
}
//--------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view data = "01234567";

    auto vec1 = convert<std::vector>(data);
    auto vec2 = convert<std::vector>(data | vws::take(20));
    fmt::println("{}\n{}\n", vec1, vec2);

#if 0
    auto vec3 = data | vws::take(1) | convert<std::vector>();
    fmt::println("{}\n", vec3);
#endif
}
```

The errors when the `#if` is changed to `#if 1` are:

```
<source>:41:59: error: no matching function for call to 'convert<template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector>()'
   41 |     auto vec3 = data | vws::take(1) | convert<std::vector>();
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:29:6: note: candidate: 'template<template<class> class Con, class Rng, class T>  requires  range<Rng> Con<T> convert(Rng&&)'
   29 | auto convert(Rng&& src) -> Con<T> {
      |      ^~~~~~~
<source>:29:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Update: No, it isn't that I'm calling this improperly. This is the way it should work. See the examples for `ranges::to` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to).

With ranges the function `convert<std::vector>(data)` is the same as `data | convert<std::vector` if `convert` is a *range adaptor*, as I have tried to implement it. I obviously have that wrong but that is not because I should be passing in an argument.

Update 2:

@super provided code that [works](https://godbolt.org/z/MaoKfnarj) but it implements an `operator|`. Per the cpprefernce example for `range_adaptor_closure` that shouldn't be necessary. There is also a no-argument version of `convert`, which I also find in the GCC 14 / trunk code for `ranges::to`. Deleting the pipeline operator provides error messages from the `ranges` library that may help me determine why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Added error messages. To see them change the #if 0 to #if 1.

Comment: Isn't the message clear enough that you're not passing any argument to `convert` while it expects one argument?

Comment: *"but I don't understand why...."* Because `convert` has one function parameter  `src` and you're not passing any argument for that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> will not compile, but I don't understand why.

The expression `convert<std::vector>()` is a **function call expression and it needs an argument** corresponding to the non-defaulted paraemter `src`. But since you're not passing any argument for the corresponding parameter `src`, you get the mentioned error.

```
<source>:41:59: error: no matching function for call to 'convert<template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector>()'
   41 |     auto vec3 = data | vws::take(1) | convert<std::vector>();
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

---

Note that you've not provided an overloaded version of `convert` that has no parameter and returns something that can take the left hand side as operand. So **to solve this** you can provide version that take no argument and returns something that can take the left hand side as operand as shown in this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MaoKfnarj).

Comment: No, that isn't the problem. Pipelines work just like iostreams with operator<<. With pipelines the operator| passes the output of the left-hand side to the parameter on the right-hand side. There is no explicit handling. For example, the 'data' is the lhs for the | and 'take' is the rhs. An element is taken from 'data' and passed to 'take'.

Comment: @rm1948 No, you're missing the point which is that `convert<std::vector>()` is a function call expression and it **needs** an argument here since the parameter `src` is not defaulted. It doesn't matter whether you use it with pipelines etc. You can't break basic c++ rules. The basic rules(the you must pass an argument) still apply.

Comment: This is the answer, your calling a function incorrectly. Note in iostreams you pas the function itself to the `operator<<`, not the result of calling it

Comment: Please go to cppreference and read the documentation for ranges::to, especially the example at the bottom. My convert is supposed to be identical to ranges:to. The last example is exactly what the error line here should accomplish. If you still feel certain of your answer, please provide code demonstrating it.

Comment: @user12002570, I've been using C++ since the 90s. I know when a function needs an argument and when it doesn't. Your answer is downvoted because, despite my explaining why it is wrong, you insist on repeating it.

Comment: @TerenceSimpson, vws::take is also a function, but it works. It receives via the pipeline operator the elements from 'data'. My 'convert' should also.

Comment: @rm1948 He is not wrong. `std::ranges::to` has an overload that takes no arguments and returns an object that implements `operator|`, that in turn will return the range depending on the value-type of the range passed in. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/MaoKfnarj).

Comment: @super, thank you for the code. I see you implemented ```operator|```. Per the example for ```range_adaptor_closure``’ on cppreference, that shouldn't be necessary. In the GCC trunk implementation of ```ranges::to```, I see an implementation that does not take a range input argument. I’ll study your and the GCC code to see if it provides any ideas.

Comment: @TerenceSimpson, I may have misunderstood what you were saying so I apologize.

Comment: @rm1948 That's correct. That's one of the things that `rng::range_adaptor_closure` does for you as a convenience. Here is [another example](https://godbolt.org/z/vGxf14hM4) using it instead.

Comment: @super, thanks again, that works. Why don't you post it as an answer instead of a comment? If you don't in the next day or so, I will and give you credit.

Comment: @rm1948 You're still missing/ignoring the actual problem.Which is that `convert<std::vector>()` is a function call expression irrespective of whether `convert` is a `range_adaptor_` or not.And so it must still pass an argument for the non-default parameter.That will never change as it is the fundamental of c++. Basically, `convert<std::vector>()` can't work(in evaluated context) unless you pass an argument for the non-defaulted parameter. You've misunderstood how pipelines and functions(call and return) work. I would recommend a beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/12002570).

Comment: @user12002570, please look at the code by super, which shows how it does work. Or consider this code from ranges:to on cpprefernece:

`auto lst = vec | std::views::take(3) | std::ranges::to<std::list<double>>();`

Comment: @rm1948 I did look at the code super gave. In particular, if you read carefully that code you'll notice that there is an overloaded version like `template <template <typename> typename Con> auto convert();`  that doesn't take any parameter. That is the reason why `convert<std::vector>();` in that [code](https://godbolt.org/z/sf8a6r36z). Looks like you missed(or ignored at this point) this. Additionally note that that version(which doesn't take any parameter) returns  `detail::Convert_impl<Con>{}`. The important thing is, that they've provided a version of `convert` that has no parameter.

Comment: @user12002570, as I mentioned, I've been doing C++ since the 90s, when Borland released Turbo C++. Seeing this code, I realized what I didn't understand. The error insisting I have an argument didn't help me reach the solution. That's why I asked for help. I gave a talk at CppNorth on ranges last year, and one illustration I used was a function that returns a `filter`. I missed the idea of a no-argument version that returned a function.

Comment: @rm1948 I've added super [example](https://godbolt.org/z/MaoKfnarj) into my answer and explained that since you've not provided an overload that has no parameter and takes left hand side as operand, this doesn't work. So to solve this we've to provide an overloaded version that takes no parameter and returns something that takes left hand side as operand. Check out the updated answer.